# Generically convert Object? to T?

Tags: c#, generics, nullable, nullable-reference-types

I have some code which works when I have a generic constraint `where T : struct`:

```
public readonly struct AnnotatedValue<T> where T : struct
{
    public AnnotatedValue(Object? value, ...)
    {
        Value = ConvertValue(value);
        ...
    }

    public T? Value { get; init; }
    ... more properties ...

    private static T? ConvertValue(Object? value)
    {
        return value switch
        {
            null => null,
            T castValue => castValue,
            _ => (T?)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T))
        };
    }
}
```

The general goal here is to convert the non-generic `Object?` into a requested type (most likely either a number, a struct, or a string); if the requested type is a value type, the result should be wrapped in a `Nullable<T>` to handle null inputs, and if the requested type is a reference type, the result is allowed to be null.

If I remove the `where T : struct` constraint, then the line `null => null` results in compiler error `CS0403 Cannot convert null to type parameter 'T' because it could be a non-nullable value type. Consider using 'default(T)' instead.`

I don't want to use `default(T)` because that will likely return a 0 value rather than a Nullable with null value.

The context is that I'm calling a non-generic method in a data source API which returns `Object?`, where the returned value might be null, a boxed value type (numeric or struct), or a String. I have access to metadata which indicates what the actual type will be, but this specific API returns it as `Object?`; my goal is to flexibly return it to a strongly-typed representation.

If the requested type is a value type, I'd like to convert the returned value into a `Nullable<foo>` corresponding to the requested value type. But if the requested type is a `String`, I'd like to return a `String?` (which is a nullable reference type, and therefore is not compatible with a `where T : struct` generic constraint).

Is there a way to achieve this kind of flexible conversion without requiring the caller to call a different method depending on whether the desired type is a value or reference type?

If I have to implement different generic methods for value `where T : struct` and reference `where T : class`, is there a way to have a wrapping method that checks run-time type info and calls into one method or the other to do the conversion?

Comment: Maybe check beforehand `value.GetType().IsValueType` what it is and then do the proper thing according if its a value types or reference types.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot return null in function whose return type is generic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76880536/6196568)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all comes down to what `T` is being passed in the value-type case. If it will be `int`, then: you can't do anything. Without a `T : struct` constraint, `T?` *doesn't mean `Nullable<T>`*; it means "`T`, and by the way, the compiler should consider this nullable from a NRT perspective". If the `T` will be `int?`, then it *already is* `Nullable<T>`, and `default(T)` already means "null".

Ultimately `T?` expresses two competing things, and you can't get the exact combination you want here. In particular, you can't tell the compiler (or more specifically, the JIT) "if the `T` *happens to be* a value-type, swap `T` for `T?`".